# Form Select and Thymeleaf

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I'm porting my app to Thymeleaf and i'm having problems in creating form select from List of Objects.

I have this form

```
    <form th:with="reservationUrl=(${price != null} ? '/book/confirm' : '/book/new')"
th:action="@{${reservationUrl}}" method="POST"
class="form-signin" th:object="${reservation}"
id="form-signin">

    <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label" for="plate"
            th:text="#{reservation.plate }">Targa</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4 input-group">
    <select th:type="*{plate}" class="form-control">
            <option th:each="p : ${plates}"
    th:value="${p.plateId}" th:text="${p.plateNumber}">Opzione</option>
            </select>
                </div>
// rest of the form
```

From the controller I have a `List<Plate> plates` and my `Reservation` has a `Plate` field, so it's a really basic select association (which worked with plain JSP)

I'm getting this exception

```
Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "p.plateId" (reservation:67)] with root cause 
Property or field 'plateId' cannot be found on object of type 'org.thymeleaf.util.EvaluationUtil$MapEntry' - maybe not public?
```

This is Plate

```
@Entity
public class Plate {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)

    private Long plateId;

    private String plateNumber;

    private String plateName;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="userId")
    @JsonBackReference(value="plates-user-reference")
    private User user;

    private boolean favourite;

    @JsonIgnore
    private boolean enabled;
    //standard getters and setters
```

Comment: What is the `${plates}`? Please post Plate item class

Comment: added Plate , thanks

Comment: Are you sure ${plates} is a List and not a Map?

Answer (score 0):

**EXAMPLE**

```
 <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="location">Pick a location:</label>
                    <select class="form-control" th:value="${appointment.location}" name="location" id="location"
                            >
                        <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" > -- select the location --</option>
                        <option>Boston</option>
                        <option>New York</option>
                        <option>Chicago</option>
                        <option>San Francisco</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
```

if you want to try a drop-down menu then yu can follow this way.